# VF Page Button Error

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I have a custom object which using to open two buttons, one works but the other doesn't not sure what im missing, any help will be greatly appreciated, im very new to the coding world(ie expert novice) Thanks

WORKING:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")} 

window.open("/apex/Accountinfomation?id="+'{!New_End_User_Record__c.Id}');
```

NOT WORKING:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")} 

window.open("/apex/Opportunityinfo?id="+'{!New_End_User_Record__c.Id}');
```

ERROR:

> Unknown constructor
>   'Opportunityinfo.Opportunityinfo(ApexPages.StandardController
>   controller)'

I tried tweaking the codes a little but have not yet cracked it, any ideas

Thanks

Comment: what does the VF page for OpportunityInfo look like?

Comment: can you post code of your Opportunityinfo page ?

Comment: You have an extension you need to fix.

Answer (score 2):

That error means that you listed the class OpportunityInfo as an extension on your visualforce page. In order to do that, one of the constructors in you class should be:

```
public class Opportunityinfo{

    public Opportunityinfo(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        //your code here 
    }

}
```

Then, your page should be as follow:

```
<apex:page standardController="New_End_User_Record__c" extensions="Opportunityinfo">
    //your page here
</apex:page>
```

Finally, you just need to redirect to the page on the button:

```
window.open("/apex/Accountinfomation?id="+'{!New_End_User_Record__c.Id}');
```

There's no need for the 'requirescripts', since your not calling the methods directly. =D

Comment: Hey Fernando, Thanks for the quick reply, i tried what you suggested but now get a separate error.                                                                        ERROR: A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

class is a reserved identifier

Comment: You will need to change your class name. Probably would be best to name it OpportunityInformation anyway, to be consistent with how you've named the Account version.

Comment: @GregG I've updated my answer. See if that helps. =D